# In elementary OS 7 cannot change grub config

Tags: system, grub

After the installation of Horus, I wanted to hide the grub menu and also add a line to prevent the following warning message:

```
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
```

However, whatever I do with the `/etc/default/grub` file, followed by `sudo update-grub`, nothing gets reflected on the grub menu.

Not only was I unable to hide a menu or change the time countdown from 30 seconds, but the previous warning message is still displaying.

Here is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -d -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

I also tried with quotes around values, but still, nothing happened

The changes were persistent after the boot after each change, but the behavior of the grub menu remained the same.

Is there a new, different way the grub works now in Horus? Should I be editing a different file?

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you @user31245, that worked :-)

Comment: I'm also looking for answers regarding this.
The above works for the timeout but how would I get quite splash working?
I have a few amd-vi warnings which are annoying that I would like to hide Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same on elementary Horus. Seems to be an older problem https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues/178 .
Adding "GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0" to /etc/default/grub and
"sudo update-grub worked for me".